# Can I use my laptop, which says 100-240V, in the USA?

Tags: usa, power

I am planning to take my laptop to the USA. The adapter says input voltage is from 100-240V. However the cord connecting the adapter to the plug mentions 2.5A 250V.

[image: Adapter][image: Cord]

Will the laptop work along with the charger in the US? Will the cord have any issue being connected to a US plug via an adapter?

Edit (25th Feb 2020) : Just to let everyone know, the laptop worked perfectly fine with an adapter. Thank you everyone for all the responses and the necessary edits to the post!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on electronics stackexchange.

Comment: @chx not really, [they don't allow consumer electronics questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)...

Comment: @chx - Probably a bad idea... If EESE doesn't reject it, the person asking the question is going to get a lot of technical detail irrelevant to the layman.

Comment: @chx Disagree: the asker is travelling and "will my electronics work at my destination" is a completely natural thing for a traveller to worry about.

Comment: Does it have the right prongs for US, might need an adapter :)

Comment: @rogerdpack I'd rather buy a suitable cable, they are detachable.

Comment: It's astounding this is not a duplciate!

Comment: @chx even if this question were on topic on a different stack, that doesn't make it off topic here

Comment: I cannot imagine that any laptop manufacturer will produce and ship power adapters that don't work across at least most countries (barring the plug)...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The cord is marked with the *maximal* voltage the insulation between the wires in it is designed to withstand. It will transmit *lower* voltages just fine and not be harmed.

It is also marked with the maximal *current* it can carry before it might begin to overheat and become a fire hazard. Since the cord is rated for 2.5 A and the power supply promises to draw at most 1.6 A, this will be fine too.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93568/discussion-on-answer-by-henning-makholm-can-i-use-my-laptop-which-says-100-240v).

Answer (score 28):

The **ONLY** relevant thing to check is the label on the power supply. It states "Input 100V-240V, 50/60Hz". Any outlet that provides voltage and frequencies in that range is safe to use.

That covers almost all countries and certainly the US which operates at 120V/60Hz. You may need a passive plug adapter (or travel adapter) since the physcial shape of the outlets is different. See https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/ for a list per country.

Do not use any type of "transformer" or "AC power converter". While most of these are safe to use, some are not and there is no need for the extra size, weight and cost.

Comment: That's not the only thing to check. The cord also needs to be able to transport the power, and with a lower voltage the power supply might draw a higher current - most cords are probably fine, and as Henning has answered, it should be fine in this case too.

Comment: The cord comes with the power supply and it would be strange if only one part of the pair was able to handle the amperage of the different systems. 2.5A at 100V is still 250 watts, which a laptop really shouldn't need.

Comment: Power supply & cord and sometimes laptop always get certified together as a system, the power supply is just the place where the logo goes.

Comment: @Hilmar: Is this also true when the line side of the power supply is a standard connector on it? If I were selling something with power bricks I'd want to source cords as a commodity and keep an option open to switch suppliers without re-certifying everything from a blank slate.

Comment: @xyious I frequently see power supplies with cords other than the ones they came with. Thought I've never seen this with such a lower power device, I definitely have seen devices with power cords that were not suitable for their voltage/current levels.

Comment: @xyious the PSU lists a maximum draw of 1.6A, so the 2.5A cord is plenty.  Standard C5/6 or C7/8 couplers used to connect low power devices and wall cords are required to be rated for 2.5A, so anything that's not a willfully unsafe knockoff cord should be safe to use. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C5/C6_coupler

Comment: The cable from the wall outlet is not fixly mounted to the PSU. Instead of a travel adapter, you may as well unplug the cable which is now there, and plug in an appropriate cable which has the US wall outlet connector on the one side and the IEC 60320 connector on the other side.

Comment: I would be very amazed if a company made a transformer that supported that voltage range and then provided a cord that would be unsafe at any voltage in that range.  Laptops simply do not draw that much power, a very light cord is enough.

Answer (score 11):

The number on the cord is a *rating* and represents the maximum safe voltage *for the cord*.  It's like automobile tires.  If you get an HR-rated tire rated 130 mph, *you are allowed to drive slower*.

That says nothing about the power supply; for that, you have to check the power supply.  You did; it appears to be the typical multi-voltage power supply that'll work anywhere from Japan to the UK, with the right cord or adapter.

That cord looks like an ["IEC C5"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320) cord, which is readily available (mail order, at least) with any nation's plug on the other end.  You can't necessarily expect to walk into any retail store and find it, especially now that *Radio Shack* is in decline.

[image]

I recommend a local cord instead of those hokey-dokey universal adapters from China, which do not have Underwriter's Laboratories or other NRTL ratings, and teardowns have shown are dreadfully unsafe.

Comment: Best buy might have them. On the same note, though, some retailers (Walmart for example) sell universal power adapters for laptops (In case you can't find a cord/travel adapter).

Comment: And adapters sold at a competent national US retail store **should** (not guaranteed) have proper UL or other NRTL listing.

Comment: What do you mean? OP's photo shows the Underwriter's Laboratories logo on the adapter. Is it somehow a fake?

Comment: @krubo assuming you're asking about the last paragraph, Harper isn't talking about the laptop power brick, but a plug adapter that would have eg an EU socket on one side and US pins on the other to let you plug an EU corded device into a US wall socket (provided the device could work at 120v/60hz too).

Comment: This kind of adapter is also usually found at airports, coming and going.  Although you'd probably pay more than at Amazon.  If you're in Europe, hardware stores usually are well stocked with them

Comment: Well for all the trouble of obtaining one via amazon or airport, I'd just order a cord and bedone with it.

Comment: this is an absolutely first-class travel tip.  Yes, it is much wiser (and, ridiculously, cheaper) to just buy "local cords" than "plug adaptors".  Good one, @Harper !

Comment: You didn't mention the current rating on the cord.  That's *unlikely* to ever be a problem for laptops, but at lower voltage you do need more current for the same power.

Comment: @PeterCordes That's taken care of by the IEC standard.  A device that takes an IEC C5 cord can't draw more than 2.5 amps, and a C5 cord must be good for at least 2.5 amps. (also in North America, UL requires cordage to be minimum 16AWG, and that's good for 10A+. The 2.5A rating on the cord relates to the connector.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine.  The cord between the adapter and the wall doesn't have any sensitive electronics in it; it's just three (or two, but this photograph looks like three) metal conductors.  As others have noted, the proposed use will not exceed the limits shown on the cord.

You'll need an adapter plug to be able to plug it in to a US wall socket, though.  If it makes your feel better, you could instead buy a whole cord with a US plug at the other end, rated and tested for US house current.

Comment: Even though the connector at the device end of the cord is standard (and replacement cords certianly _exist_), I suspect that locating a shop that sells them alone would be rather more involved than picking up a plug adapter at the airport ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm in my experience, yes, that is the case.  Plug adapters are much easier to come by.

Comment: Good quality, correctly matched plug adapters that maintain a proper eath path on the other hand can be harder to come by :(

Comment: If this is for a business trip, the local IT support team might have a suitable cord they could give you.  On previous business trips, I have done exactly this and then 'neglected' to return the cord afterwards.  I now have a selection of power cords - UK, US and European - which will plug in to the power adaptor for my laptop.  I now just take the right one with me when I travel.

Comment: @Nick *That's* where all the cables go!

Comment: And the company probably has loads of cords, since the cords tend to outlast the laptops...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes. United States AC voltage is 120V 60Hz, which is within the input range specified on the PSU.

Also: Think about it. If they didn't, you would be reading about a lot of fried laptops all the time. Given that laptops are intended to be traveled with, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Just a note: While it may be rated as 120V, it is normally 110V.